# Why won't it run everytime I got an incoming message in C#?

Tags: c#, event-handling, task, streamreader, streamwriter

I tested this code with placing a breakpoint in Monodevelop, running on a Raspbian. This app needs to communicate with a Windows, with a C# console application. 
Although the timer1_Tick method prints the incoming message everytime (and it clearly prints the new message, because there I clear the message variable everytime after an incoming message), it seems to be that the OnNewData doesn't run everytime, when there's an incoming message. 
I ask new incoming message with sending the "mes" out in the timer1_Tick. 
I don't process the other kind of incoming messages in that method, but for the response for "mes", this place would be the best for processing. The reason is the "mes" creates answer types ("", " type answers), what I can get anytime. 
I don't know what is the problem. Any idea? How could this happen, if the textbox is being refreshed nicely after each new incoming message?

```
public partial class Form0 : Form
{

    public static string ReadCharactersIntoString(){
        char c='c';
        string outputString=String.Empty;
        do{
            c=(char)streamReader.Read();
            outputString=outputString+c;
        }while(c!='>');
        return outputString;
    }
    async void OnNewData(object sender, EventArgs e){
        message = Form0.ReadCharactersIntoString ();

        //work with message variable works unreliable...
        //sometimes this method runs, when there's an incoming message, sometimes it's not...
        //although tick method prints the message everytime...
        //why? how to solve this?

        reseter.Set ();
    }
    public void AcceptMessages(){
        while (true) {
            try{
            if (streamReader!=null && streamReader.Peek () > 0) {
                newIncomingDataEvent.Invoke(this,EventArgs.Empty);
                reseter.WaitOne ();
            }
            }catch{

            }
        }
    }
    public static async Task Waiting(){
        while (message == null || message[message.Length-1]!='>') {
        }
    }
    public static async Task<string> CollectingAnswer(){
        await Waiting();

        return message;
        //when the answer is completely collected, it gives me back
    }
    public void ConnectionEstablisher()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!activeConnection)
            {
                try
                {    
                    socketForServer = new TcpClient(ip, port);
                    networkStream = socketForServer.GetStream();
                    streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);
                    streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
                    streamReader.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                    streamWriter.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;                      
                    activeConnection = true;

                    newIncomingDataEvent+=OnNewData;
                    reseter = new ManualResetEvent (true);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    activeConnection = false;                      
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Visible && activeConnection)
        {
            try
            {
                streamWriter.Write("mes");
                streamWriter.Flush();
                textBoxSending.AppendText("mes" + Environment.NewLine);

                collectAnswer=CollectingAnswer();
                outputString=await collectAnswer;
                message=null;

                textBoxAccepting.AppendText(outputString + Environment.NewLine);

                //this always prints the incoming response message...
```

Comment: Do not understand me wrong, but the code style is a little dubious. using static methods/static fields/async tasks, a while loop without instructions/delay/wait events, it doesn't fit nicely together. It looks like _too much at the same time_. Walk before you run. I would rather start with the asynchronous [`BeginReceive()/EndReceive()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) version methods of the socket, which is much easier and more clear.

Comment: I know. This is my first commercial project and it has tons of codes being commented and uncommented again and again. Unfortunately this situation happened, so I will be happy if this thing even works.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I have tried to implement the MSDN example for that. But the example is not completed. People in IRC told me to use TaskFactory.FromAsync instead, but that also doesn't have neither a complete, nor an incomplete example. In addition to this, somebody told me he found that in a book called "Async in C# 5.0" but I think Monodevelop (what I need to use to develop under Raspbian) doesn't even support C# 5.0.

Comment: If you're using tcp, you should have a protocol. How would you know a message is completed? Are you sending a length of data before you sent the string?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I tried to check that with Task Waiting(). I don't send the length of data.

Comment: So, how would you know if a message is split up into 2 packages? You'll receive half messages

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen these are just short string messages. I have never caught 2 packages.

Comment: You should, tcp is streaming and this will become a problem not far away..  I would fix it by sending the length of the data before en read until all data is received.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Do you mean the other side should send an integer first, and then send the actual message?
Also we should stick on the first question I asked.